# How to remove an element from XML file using Linq to XML and lambda expression

Tags: c#, xml, linq-to-xml

I have an xml as below

```
<Person>
   <Name>xxx</Name>
   <Age>xx</Age>
   <Data>xxxx</Data>
</Person>
<Person>
   <Name>xxx</Name>
   <Age>xx</Age>
   <Data>xxxx</Data>
</Person>
<Person>
   <Name>xxx</Name>
   <Age>xx</Age>
   <Data>xxxx</Data>
</Person>
```

How to remove `<Data>` element from the tree using Linq to XML, Lamda Expression in C#? where `<Data>` is a auto generated element and XML structure may vary.

Comment: LINQ is a functional DSL - it's good for getting information, not for altering data. Why not remove the element in the old, OOP way?

Answer (score 2):

it all depends on what element you want to remove but you can use something like this

```
XDocument people = XDocument.Load("filenamre.xml");
IEnumerable<XElement> Person = people.Element("Person");
//gets  the element you want to remove based on value 
XElement name = Person.Where(p => p.Element("xxx").Value == "1").FirstOrDefault();
//removes the name 
name.Remove();
//create a new file without the element 
people.Save(Server.MapPath("Newfilenamre.xml"));
```

Comment: If value of that element is auto generated, how to remove it?

Comment: well how are you going to remove an element if you do not know what element you want to remove you can remove specific person like second or third

Answer (score -1):

Removing element other than first one. Means only first must be there rest all must be deleted.